# No error! Can't find the solution with java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion, newtons-method

```
import java.util.*;

public class NRootx {

    public static Double NRmethod (Double num, int root, Double guess){
        guess= num/(root+1); //first guess  

        Double guess_output=1.0;

        for (int i=1;i<=root; i++)
        {
            guess_output *= guess;
        }

        Double error= guess_output-num;
        error = error * 0.001;
        guess = guess - error;

        if (Math.abs(error)>=0.000001)
            return NRmethod(num, root, guess); //Recursion 
        else
            return guess;

           //I can't find out the problem now. Java.lang.StackOverFlow error is showing. 

        }
    }
}

// Main function 
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double x;
    int n;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the value of x: ");
    x=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the value of n: ");
    n=sc.nextInt();
    Double guess=x/(n+1);
    Double ans= NRmethod(x,n,guess);
    System.out.println("The value of y is ="+ans);
}
```

Please someone help me to solve this. I am being tired of doing this for many time.

Comment: Not related to the `StackOverflowError` issue, but use `double` instead of `Double`, so you don't need to create unnecessary `Double` objects.

Comment: Also: `guess_output = Math.pow(guess, root);`, no need for for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You never change `root` and `num`, and you reset `guess` in each call to `guess= num/(root+1);`, so you get an endless recursion, leading to `StackOverflowError`.

I'm not sure what the correct logic should be, but to prevent the endless recursion you must either pass different values of `root` or `num` to each recursive call, or don't reset `guess` at the start of the method.

Comment: Oh thank you. that's why I promote user to give the value of guess.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer myself. Asking for a guess will solve the problem. Do not need to set the guess like the code I have given. However, I do not know the reason but it solved the problem. Thank you.